# AntD React InputNumber Increase/Decrease buttons appear to start infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, antd

I am experiencing some unusual behaviour with [AntD InputNumber component](https://ant.design/components/input-number/), specifically using the up/down incrementation buttons:

[image]

I have a very basic implementation of the component as follows:

```
<InputNumber min={1} max={10} defaultValue={3} onChange={changeWeight} />
```

calling function:

```
  function changeWeight(weight) {
    console.log(weight);
  }
```

On the face of it, it all seems to work fine, as I click on the increment button, I see the result in my console for each click. 3 clicks up and my console reads:

[image]

Great! However, if I then place a debugger inside the called function like so:

```
  function changeWeight(weight) {
    debugger;
    console.log(weight);
  }
```

then refresh the screen and hit the increment button once, I hit my breakpoint, console is logged, I hit continue then instead of the process finishing, it goes straight back to the breakpoint again. The function is called again and again infinitely it seems. I have found if you put a max value on the InputNumber component it does stop at that number. The below console log is from hitting the button just once, but the breakpoint being hit many times...

[image]

Again, if I remove the debugger breakpoint, all seems normal and the console logs just the once when the button is clicked.

Also, if I type numbers into the component it only hits the debugger breakpoint once. Just these buttons seem to be causing a problem.

Has anyone else experienced this or have any ideas as to what may be causing it? I am very confused.

Comment: Can you specify the antd version. When i click on increment, it just stops at where i place the debugger. I tested this using antd@4.9.4.

Comment: Is this causing any issue in your program?

Comment: I am using v4.16.13 so that is interesting. I have tried this on a new component in an existing project so will try creating a fresh new empty project and see if I can replicate.